# The second eventlistener and device ready is not working in Index.js in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using multiple html for login,map pages and index.html page. My index.html is mentioned below along with index.js page as below but I was unable to interlink these pages and display a simple alert dialog in line number 16.The device ready is not called at all but the function func1 is working but the GPSTrackButton is not working.I used the plugin from this webpage. https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Tutorial-for-Windows.
The first event listener is executing but the control is not going to the second event listener i.e.,  parentElement.getElementById("btnGpsTracker").addEventListener("click",this.onGpsTrackButton);},

.Can anyone help in making this app work? The code is in the image below.
[CODE IN THIS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsSku.png)

Comment: first thing I could see is that the index.is is included twice in HTML file

Comment: even if i remote it that will not give me a solution..as there is some problem with deviceready or the event listener.

Comment: @user27766452 any error trace?

Comment: @user27766452 i guess you deleted your comment. Could you share the code?